# Jest coverage report unknown

Tags: webpack, jestjs, babel-jest

I want to integrate Jest in my webpack flow, I have installed following installed following dependencies

```
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
    "babel-7-jest": "^21.3.3",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.19",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "file-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "jest": "^23.6.0",
    "jest-cli": "^23.6.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.3",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.0",
    "webpack": "^4.20.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.4.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.9"
```

Below is my jest config

```
rootDir: path.resolve(__dirname, 'test'),
verbose: true,
collectCoverage: true,
collectCoverageFrom: ['src/**/*.{js}'],
coverageReporters: ['json', 'html']
```

When I run npm test with the below script I get the following output where test's run properly but the coverage is unkown everytime

```
"coverage": "jest --coverage --config=jest.config.js",

=============================== Coverage summary ===============================
Statements   : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
Branches     : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
Functions    : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
Lines        : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
================================================================================
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.491s
Ran all test suites.
```

All its testing is plain javascript.

Comment: Did you find something on this? I'm having the same issue here!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is your directory layout:

```
- ./project_root
 |_./jest.config.js
 |_./src/
 |_./test/
```

Either set your `rootDir` to `project_root` or leave it to default value. Optionally, if there's any folder that should be excluded from coverage report other than `node_modules`, add them to [coveragePathIgnorePatterns](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#coveragepathignorepatterns-array-string).

From Jest documentation [on rootDir](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#rootdir-string):

> The root directory that Jest should scan for tests **and modules** within. If you put your Jest config inside your package.json and want the root directory to be the root of your repo, the value for this config param will default to the directory of the package.json.